# Time Handler inside a time handler

Tags: andengine

```
 TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(.7f, true,  new ITimerCallback() {
                    private int grab_shell=0;
                    private int loop_count=0;

                    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                        if ((shell[0].getCurrentTileIndex()>0)&&(loop_count==0))
                        {
                            grab_shell=shell[0].getCurrentTileIndex();
                            shell[0].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                        }
                        if(grab_shell>0)
                        {   
                            current_house++;
                            if(current_house==15)
                            {
                                current_house=0;
                            }
                            if((grab_shell==1)&&(current_house!=7)&&(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()!=0))
                            {

                                    grab_shell=2+shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex();
                                    shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(0);

                                }
                            }

                            else if ((grab_shell==1)&&(current_house!=7)&&(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()==0))
                            {
                                shell[7].setCurrentTileIndex(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()+1);
                                shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                            }
                            shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()+1);
                            grab_shell--;
                        }

                        if(grab_shell==0)
                        {
                        unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                        }
                        loop_count++;
                        }
```

My problem is how can i create a delay within this code

```
    if((grab_shell==1)&&(current_house!=7)&&(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()!=0))
       {        grab_shell=2+shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex();
                                    shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                            }
```

This code was inside the a timerhandler. how can i do that? please show me.
This part of code has two action compared to the other conditions that is why i have to make this part a little bit delayed by 1.4seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer handlers can be nested. This means you can have a timer handler inside a timerhandler. The only thing that you need to make sure is that you unregister your handlers in order to avoid unwanted behavior. I also assume that you want the timer handler created with the if statement that you are pointing out.

```
TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(.7f, true,  new ITimerCallback() {
                private int grab_shell=0;
                private int loop_count=0;

                public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                    if ((shell[0].getCurrentTileIndex()>0)&&(loop_count==0))
                    {
                        grab_shell=shell[0].getCurrentTileIndex();
                        shell[0].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                    }
                    if(grab_shell>0)
                    {   
                        current_house++;
                        if(current_house==15)
                        {
                            current_house=0;
                        }
                        if((grab_shell==1)&&(current_house!=7)&&(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()!=0))
                        {
                    //here
                    TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(1.4f, true,  new ITimerCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                    grab_shell=2+shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex();
                    shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                   //unregister timer handler

                    }

                 });

                            }
                        }

                        else if ((grab_shell==1)&&(current_house!=7)&&(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()==0))
                        {
                            shell[7].setCurrentTileIndex(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()+1);
                            shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                        }
                        shell[current_house].setCurrentTileIndex(shell[current_house].getCurrentTileIndex()+1);
                        grab_shell--;
                    }

                    if(grab_shell==0)
                    {
                    unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                    }
                    loop_count++;
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it really fits my idea.